# How to plot 2d array with highcharts easily?

Tags: highcharts

I have a 2d Array containing an heatmap representation 6000*6000 pixels, i saw the example on highchart site and especially this one 
    jsfiddle.net/tZ6GP/5/
and it works.
 But my grid is regulary spaced so it's a pity to be forced to create a new array 3 times bigger my original.

Do you know if there is a mean or an other type of chart more simple that could be lighter ?  or maybe another library

Best regards

Comment: You can try to use boost module, which increases performance. Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap-canvas/

Comment: Thanks but was already activated.

Comment: Did it solve your problem ?

Comment: Not really because i 'm still forced to create a 3 times larger array before displaying data

Comment: The heatmap chart creates svg rectangles for each of the elements on the input data, even when they do not even fit in the number of pixels that the chart has available on the screen. I have been dealing with this for a while now and decided to use the heatmap just for the axis labels but do the rendering on top of it on my own.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6751